# JSOUP: How to get Href?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I've this HTML code:

```
 <td class="topic starter"><a href="http://www.test.com">Title</a></td>
```

I want to extract "Title" and the URL, so I did this:

```
 Elements titleUrl = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "topic starter");
 String title = titleUrl.text();
```

And this works for the title, but for the URL I tried the following:

```
 String url = titleUrl.html();
 String url = titleUrl.attr("a [href]");
 String url = titleUrl.attr("a[href]");
 String url = titleUrl.attr("href");
 String url = titleUrl.attr("a");
```

But no one works and I'm not able to get the URL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
Element link = doc.select("td.topic.starter > a").first();
String url = link.attr("href");
```

You first select the `a` element and then extract its attribute `href`.

Comment: Have a look at my edited post, this should work. No, you can't extract the url from the `td` element, because it is an attribute of a different element.

Comment: @helloimyourmind Well, that does basically the same thing as my code, in two selects instead of one. You also should not require the `toString()` because `attr()` already returns a String.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Does your solution improve performance of double select?

Comment: I don't know if it improves the performance, since I don't know how it has been implemented internally - it certainly shouldn't make it slower. It improves the readability, though.

Comment: You need to add .first();

doc.select("td.topic.starter > a").first();